# jinja2 escape sequence of interpreted characters

Tags: jinja2

I would like to output `{#` in html, but this is the beginning of a Jinja2 comment. This is not coming from a template variable. Just plain html in my template.

Any help ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try this...

```
{{ '{#' }}
```

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#escaping

Hope this helps!